# How to convert scientific notation into normal double expression

Tags: android, double

I have problem in dealing with scientific notation. In order to simplifeid problem, I used constants instead of variables, and the statement as follows :

```
double temp = 211.751 * 110 * 500 * 0.9971;
Log.e("Temp : ", Double.toString(temp));
```

the result is : 1.1612530715499999E7

what I want is : 11,612,530.72

My question is how to convert the result into normal expression and formatted to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 9):

```
Double.parseDouble("9.78313E+2");
```

gives you

```
978.313
```

and then

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(number));
```

try it out

Comment: It can't work. May be my question is not clear enough, I mean the result itself is a double, and I want convert it to string in normal double expression with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Yeah its not clear to me.. provide the input and output with datatype.

Comment: To made it simple, how to convert the double variable "temp" into string without scientific notation?

Comment: @xpw what do you think is the return type of `formatter.format(number)`?

Comment: @sam: This is still relevant in 2022. I wrote: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");` `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);` `String str = df.format(dbl);` But when I pass **1234567890.0123456789** as the double value, the return value becomes **1,234,567,890.0123458**. Similarly, when I pass **12345678.0123456789**, it returns **12,345,678.01234568**. You can see the fractional precision is lost. But when I pass **12345678.899**, it returns **12,345,678.899**. This time the precision is retained. Why is this happening randomly? How can I make sure the precision remains correct always?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
double temp = 211.751 * 110 * 500 * 0.9971;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#00,000,000.00");
Log.e("Temp : ",format.format(temp));
```

Comment: I wrote: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");` `df.setMaximumFractionDigits(340);` `String str = df.format(dbl);` But when I pass **1234567890.0123456789** as the double value, the return value becomes **1,234,567,890.0123458**. Similarly, when I pass **12345678.0123456789**, it returns **12,345,678.01234568**. You can see the fractional precision is lost. But when I pass **12345678.899**, it returns **12,345,678.899**. This time the precision is retained. Why is this happening randomly? How can I make sure the precision remains correct always? Please help in sorting it out.